# Multi column or table row for chapter headers?

Tags: tables, chapters, multicol, multicolumn, multirow

I'm trying to recreate this layout for chapter headers for a book:

[image: Chapter header]

One side is the chapter name and the others is just numbers for the chapter count. I tried making this work with tables and multicols, but I can't get them to both top align and I can't reduce the width of the left-hand column enough to make the title fit properly.

How would you go about implementing this with LaTex? Possible?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Do you mean recreating the chapter header or chapter title? Because it looks like the headers are not related to your question. And please show us which document class are you using (report, book, memoir, etc.)

Comment: I'm using books \documentclass{book}. I'm working on the header of the chapter. So, chapter title, numbering, spacing, text, etc. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `totcount` package along with `\regtotcounter{chapter}` command and then you can refer to the total chapters counts in your document by the command \total{chapter}.

To apply this into your chapter title, one way is using `\usepackage{titlesec}` to change the default title format to include the total number of chapters, and perhaps using `\sffamily` (from what appears in your picture) as the font of your chapter title.

Assuming you are using the `book` class (as you didn't specify), with total of 3 chapters, you get an output like this

[image]

Full code

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{totcount}
\regtotcounter{chapter}
%
\usepackage{lipsum}
%
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\sffamily\Huge\bfseries}{\thechapter/\total{chapter}}{1em}{}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Introduction}
    \section{Structure}
    This book consists of \total{chapter} chapters.
%   
    \chapter{Finding The Leaks in Your Funnel}
    \section{Leaks}
    \lipsum
%
    \chapter{Finding Something Else}
    \section{Something}
        \lipsum
\end{document}
```

---

**EDIT**

If you want multi-line numbering (with a smaller font for chapter numbering), change `\titleformat` command to

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\sffamily\bfseries}{\raisebox{2ex}{\normalsize \parbox[t][0cm]{0cm}{ \thechapter \\ / \\ \total{chapter} }}}{3em}{\Huge}
```

[image]

You may change the parameters of `2ex`, `\normalsize`, or `\Huge` to your liking.

Comment: there is a new line between `\thechapter` and `\total{chapter}`

Comment: @js bibra Yea thanks I noticed, but I wasn't sure he meant that or it was just the small width space of the numbering that forced it at a new line!

Comment: The `\thechapter` and `\total{chapter}` may even need to shrink their fontsize.

Comment: This is awesome. Thank you @hesham! Any way to force the numbering on 3 lines like the original?

Comment: @egarbugli Sorry for the late response. The answer has been edited based on your comment.

Comment: Amazing. Thank you! :-)

Comment: @egarbugli If you think an answer is helpful, you may consider upvoting (by clicking on the up arrow next to the answer) and/or marking it as the accepted answer (by clicking on the checkmark ✓)

Comment: I just did. Thanks. Still learning how this community works. :-)